# Accessing specific case from F# DU

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

Suppose I have the following DU:

```
type Something =
| A of int
| B of string * int
```

Now I use it in a function like this:

```
let UseSomething = function
| A(i) -> DoSomethingWithA i
| B(s, i) -> DoSomethingWithB s i
```

That works, but I've had to deconstruct the DU in order to pass it to the DoSomethingWith* functions. It feels natural to me to try to define DoSomethingWithA as:

```
let DoSomethingWithA (a: Something.A) = ....
```

but the compiler complains that the type A is not defined.

It seems entirely in keeping with the philosophy of F# to want to restrict the argument to being a Something.A, not just any old int, so am I just going about it the wrong way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The important thing to note is that `A` and `B` are constructors of the *same* type `Something`. So you will get inexhaustive pattern matching warning if you try to use `A` and `B` cases separately.

IMO, deconstructing all cases of DUs is a good idea since it is type-safe and forces you to think of handling those cases even you don't want to. The problem may arise if you have to deconstruct DUs repetitively in the same way. In that case, defining `map` and `fold` functions on DUs might be a good idea:

```
let mapSomething fa fb = function
| A(i) -> fa i
| B(s, i) -> fb s i
```

Please refer to excellent [Catamorphism series](http://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2008/04/06/catamorphisms-part-two/) by @Brian to learn about fold on DUs.

That also said that your example is fine. What you really process are `string` and `int` values after deconstruction.

You can use [Active Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx) to consume two cases separately:

```
let (|ACase|) = function A i -> i | B _ -> failwith "Unexpected pattern B _"
let (|BCase|) = function B(s, i) -> (s, i) | A _ -> failwith "Unexpected pattern A _"

let doSomethingWithA (ACase i) = ....
```

but inferred type of `doSomethingWithA` is still the same and you get an exception when passing `B _` to the function. So it's a wrong thing to do IMO.

Comment: Thanks for the link to catamorphisms - looks like a great series, and your suggestion of a map function makes sense. I agree that handling all cases of a DU is a good thing: it just still feels like once I know I have an A, I should be able to pass that A around rather than being forced to pass a Something. Maybe I'm being tripped up by my OO background + knowledge that both A and B are implemented as subtypes of Something?

Comment: +1 "deconstructing all cases of DUs is a good idea since it is type-safe and forces you to think of handling those cases even you don't want to"

Comment: @Akash: You're right. Inheritance can be used to emulate DUs, but pattern matching and exhaustive check become much more tedious. In terms of difference (in strength and weakness, etc) between OOP and DUs, I find this paper http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~wcook/papers/OOPvsADT/CookOOPvsADT90.pdf very inspiring.

Comment: Thanks for that link too - will take me some time to go through it! I wasn't suggesting using inheritance instead of DUs, rather I meant that because I happen to have seen how DUs are implemented in F# (reflector!), it feels wrong to *not* be able to pass an A/B around _once I have done the exhaustive checking_.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused about what A and B represent? I think of them as types (i.e. A is a type that wraps an int), whereas maybe they are nothing more than labels (i.e. A is label identifying a particular int)? If the latter is true, then I can understand why I can't pass an A around.

Comment: The latter is true. The former is the implementation details in OOP's point of view, which may or may not be relevant.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are accurate: in F# `A` and `B` are constructors, not types, and this is the traditional approach taken by strongly typed functional languages like Haskell or the other languages in the ML family.  However, there are other approaches - I believe that in Scala, for example, `A` and `B` would actually be subclasses of `Something`, so you could use those more specific types where it makes sense to do so.  I'm not completely sure what tradeoffs are involved in the design decision, but generally speaking inheritance makes type inference harder/impossible (and true to the stereotype type inference in Scala is much worse than in Haskell or the ML languages).

Comment: Thanks, I find it interesting that my mental model is closer to Scala's approach than F#'s. But I'm not going to move to Scala any day soon, so I need to reset my thinking!

Answer (score 3):

`A` is not a type, it is just a constructor for `Something`. There's no way you can avoid pattern matching, which is not necessarily a bad thing.

That said, F# does offer a thing called *active patterns*, for instance

```
let (|AA|) = function 
    | A i -> i 
    | B _ -> invalidArg "B" "B's not allowed!"
```

which you can then use like this:

```
let DoSomethingWithA (AA i) = i + 1
```

But there's no real reason why you would want to do that! You still do the same old pattern matching under the hood, plus you risk the chance of a runtime error.

In any case, your implementation of `UseSomething` is perfectly natural for F#.

Comment: It's always instructive to look at the IL code produced by the F# compiler in the Visual Studio object browser or IL Spy. In IL, Something.A and Something.B really _are_ subclasses of Something. As a consequence, in non-F# languages (e.g., C# or VB.Net), one _can_ declare parameters as Something.A or Something.B, the way @Akash suggested.

Comment: @MarcSigrist this is only partially true. Nullary cases for instance do not generate nested types, whereas some branches (such as the `None` constructor) are represented with `null`.

Comment: Yes, of course. It is true in the specific case mentioned, but not necessarily in other cases.